# html script how to disappear and re-appear a fixed menu bar when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to make similar menu bar like [this](http://www.billykick.com/)

But the logic stuff is kinda hard. >.<

I'm using jquery script
Here's my sample and it sucks lol..

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/855gB/1/)

html:

```
<html>
    <!--- to float menubar and stay on top animation XD --->
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var num = 200; //number of pixels before modifying styles
        $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
                $('.menu').addClass('fixed');

            } else {
                $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .menu {
            background:#555555;
            color:#FFF;
            height:50px; 
            position:absolute;
            top:200px;
            border-bottom: 10px solid #e6e6ce;
            width:1100px;
            margin-left:100px;
            margin-right:100px;
        }
        .fixed {
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="menu">
        Home &nbsp about &nbsp 
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working, what "logic stuff" are you finding difficult? The jsFiddle is working as I would expect.

Comment: i want to disapear the menu when you scroll top and apear when scroll down like www.billykick.com but idk how to do the conditions in jquery :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `style="display:none;"` in `menu` class

Then just hide and show the menu with .hide() and .show() method.

```
var num = 200; //number of pixels before modifying styles
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
        $('.menu').show();

    } else {
        $('.menu').hide();
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');

    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dGVY8/

Comment: thanks but theres more did u know how to achieve the fade in and fade out animation effect?

Comment: Just replace .show() with .fadeIn() http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ If you want to specify duration use .fadeIn(200). 200 are milliseconds. Use fadeOut() instead of .hide()

Answer (score 1):

You might also would like to [look at this](http://lirancohen.github.io/stickUp/). Personally I found this jQuery solution quite fancy